# SQL JOIN duplicating rows

Tags: mysql

I am trying to join 2 tables and grab a single row for each item. The default value for the rating is 45. Every time there is a different rating within a category, each item row is duplicated. Below is an example schema, data, and result.

Table 1
*--------------------------*
ofid | item  | category
*--------------------------*
  1  | item1 | cat1
  2  | item2 | cat1
  3  | item3 | cat1

Table 2
*---------------------------*
ofid | rating | category
*---------------------------*
  1  |   37   | cat1
  2  |   42   | cat1
  3  |   45   | cat1

Result
*------------------------------------*
ofid | item | rating | category
*------------------------------------*
  1  | item1 | 37 | cat1
  1  | item1 | 42 | cat1
  1  | item1 | 45 | cat1
  2  | item2 | 37 | cat1
  2  | item2 | 42 | cat1
  2  | item2 | 45 | cat1
  3  | item3 | 37 | cat1
  3  | item3 | 42 | cat1
  3  | item3 | 45 | cat1

Expected Result
*------------------------------------*
ofid | item | rating
*------------------------------------*
  1  | item1 | 37
  2  | item2 | 42
  3  | item3 | 45

Query:
`SELECT p.ofid,p.item,r.rating FROM table1 AS p INNER JOIN table2 AS r ON p.category = r.category WHERE p.category = "cat1" GROUP BY p.ofid,p.category,r.rating`

I've tried adding DISTINCT, JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN.... help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that your "expected result" has four columns while your select statement is only selecting three columns.  I assume this is a typo.

Comment: Quite correct. Edited. Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 2):

According to what you want in your expected result, I believe you are joining on the wrong field.  Below should work.

```
Select
  p.ofid,
  p.item,
  r.rating
From table1 p 
Inner Join table2 r On r.ofid = p.ofid
where p.category ="cat1"
```

Comment: Correctomundo!!!! I think I'd just been staring at this for entirely too long. Kudos sir!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding but don't you want to join on the ofids as well?

```
SELECT p.ofid,p.item,r.rating 
FROM table1 AS p 
INNER JOIN table2 AS r 
    ON p.category = r.category AND p.ofid = r.ofid 
WHERE p.category = "cat1" 
GROUP BY p.ofid,p.category,r.rating
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a perfectly normal result, as you're grouping on all 3 fields you're selecting. If you want a SINGLE copy of each ofid in the result set, then do a `GROUP BY p.ofid` only.

Comment: I've also tried that. It indeed gives the correct number of rows, however it gives 45 for all 3 ratings.

Comment: That's also expected. What do you want the ratings to be? average of all the ratings for that ofid? then `select avg(p.ofid) ...`

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to join on `ofid` in addition to (or instead of?) `category`. All three entries in `table1` have `"cat1"`, and all three entires in `table2` also have `"cat1"`, so each record in `table1` matches all three records in `table2`. Thus, 3 x 3 = 9 rows expected in the result. You probably want something like this:

```
SELECT p.ofid,p.item,r.rating
FROM table1 AS p
INNER JOIN table2 AS r ON p.category = r.category
                       AND p.ofid = r.ofid
WHERE p.category = "cat1"
GROUP BY p.ofid,p.category,r.rating
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are trying to do?

```
SELECT p.offid,p.item,r.rating,r.category FROM table1 p INNER JOIN table2 r
ON p.category = r.category
AND p.offid = r.offid
WHERE p.category = 'cat1'
```